# What is the algorithm behind gimp feather edges on selections?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, gimp

I have seen a checkbox in the select-by-color and fuzzy-select tool labeled "feather edges" with a radius as a parameter. What is the algorithm it uses?

without feather:
[image: without feather]

with feather:
[image: with feather]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimentally, there is very little difference between feathering the selection by 20px, and applying a 20px Gaussian blur on the selection mask.

The map of the difference (circle selection feathered to 20px or selection mask with a 20px Gaussian blur). The white is where the value of the difference is 4:

[image]

Edit: confirmed by the source code